# Minecraft is still crashing even after the 1.2_01 patch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft 1.2 came out earlier this week, and soon after was followed by another bugfix patch, putting us at 1.2_01. However, the game is still quite unstable for me:

- I am unable to go more than 10
  minutes without minecraft crashing to
  a black screen. The program becomes
  unresponsive, and needs to be closed
  via the task manager. Because of this
  chunks are not saved (irritating, to say the least) so I find myself having to constantly
  hit "esc" to manually save the chunks for fear of losing progress in my world.
- Sometimes, when starting up the program, nothing on the initial log-in screen can be clicked, and the program is unresponsive. Eventually, it may or may not replace the log-in screen with a "cannot connect to minecraft.net" dialog.

Am I the only one experiencing such difficulties? If others are having the same problems (I wasn't able to turn up anything recent with google alone), is there a way to fix this temporarily before another bugfix patch, 1.2_02, is sent out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the render distance from "far" to "normal" has prevented the crash from reoccurring.

Comment: A bit late but still, this might have something to do with a lack of ram? If you have time, you could set it (render distance) back to far and see how much ram is allocated under F3, should be in the top right. If it's anywhere near the amount of memory you have available that would probably be it, the unresponsiveness is probably windows writing parts of the game to the hard drive (and reading them back from it).

Comment: @Yourdoom, except I haven't changed my RAM since buying minecraft, and it has worked flawlessly previously.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a 64 bit OS but using 32 bit java the game is known to crash a lot, simple fix is installing 64 bit java runtime (findable on: http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)

Comment: Interesting. This applies to my situation, however I didn't have this problem before the patch. Worth looking into, at any rate.

Comment: Okay, I already had 64 bit java installed, so this wasn't it.

Comment: Just "having it installed" doesn't mean it's being used. Are you sure the 64-bit JRE version is the default Java in your system?

Comment: I had the exact same problem and it was completely fixed by the 64-bit JRE. I would actually recommend that you uninstall all JREs and reinstall the 64-bit one only, just so you know for fact that you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that we can do anything, except to wait.

If you haven't modified your system lately, it's the game. On the other hand my brother is also experiencing the black screen issue (WinXP SP3), but I don't (Ubuntu 10.10). So it could also be platform-specific. But as I said, if you haven't changed something lately, it's the game. You'll have to wait for a patch.

Comment: This is what I'm inclined to believe, but I haven't been able to find much corroboration by other users that they're having the same kinds of difficulties.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: You sure? Because [I can find plenty of that](http://www.minecraftforum.net/search.php?keywords=black+screen&terms=all&author=&fid[]=17&sc=1&sf=all&sr=posts&sk=t&sd=d&st=0&ch=300&t=0&submit=Search).

Comment: the link you provided is dead "Cannot provide search at this time". And I've found many more instances of "Black screen crash" dated back to October, post-Halloween update. It's not that I doubt they're out there, it's that I can't find anything *recent*.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Sorry for the broken link, it works for me (though, I'm registered at the Forum). Anyway, it's basically a search for 'Black Screen', which yields tons of results from within the last days. And you're right, yes, it doesn't mean that it's a *new* issue.